# using NumberFormatter to produce output with a chosen number of significant digits in decimal or scientific notation in php

Tags: php, format, digits

I'd like to be able to print a number with a given number of significant digits, either in scientific format or in decimal format.
I am trying to use NumberFormatter, but I'm finding some inconsistency. It is also possible that I'm not entirely understanding the syntax for NumberFormatter. 
The documentation does not provide a lot of relevant examples, and I'm having a hard time finding those on the web.

So, the following code seem to produce almost what I need

```
// create number formatter
$nf = new NumberFormatter('it', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

// force the use of significant digits? I'm not sure this is the right way of using this 
// option, but if I omit this line, the following ones have no effect
$nf->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS_USED,1);

// set the same value for the maximum and minimum number of significant digits should force a 
// given number of s.d.
$nf->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS, 3);
$nf->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS, 3);

// test format: the following gives what I expect, "1,31" 
// (Italian locale uses a comma for the decimal separator).
echo $nf->format(1.306);
```

However, it does not produce what I want with "halfway numbers".
For instance `echo $nf->format(1.305);` produces 1,30 instead of the expected 1,31. But `echo $nf->format(1.315);` gives what I expect: 1,32 .

This affects both the DECIMAL and SCIENTIFIC formats.

I thought this has to do with a "ROUND_HALFEVEN" option, so I tried adding

```
$nf->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::ROUNDING_MODE,NumberFormatter::ROUND_HALFUP);
```

However, it seems that this "cures" the problem only for the SCIENTIFIC format and only when the result is an integer.
That is: if the first line in the code is as above (DECIMAL) the numbers 1.305; 22.45; 222.5 give 1,30; 22.4; 222; instead of 1,31; 22.5; 223.
If I choose the SCIENTIFIC format the same three numbers are rounded up to integers, with the last producing the expected result: 1,00E0; 2,00E0; 2,23E2.

So, either HALFUP is not the right option to fix my problem, or I'm using it wrong.

Of course I could try and write my own function for the correct number of significant digits (or copy it from examples) but I thought that setting the correct options in NumberFormatter should do that for me.

Any insight is appreciated.

Francesco

Comment: But 1.315 seems to have exactly the same problem, and it is rounded up "correctly". Also, 0,125 has no problem at all, and it's rounded up "wrong".

Comment: The above comment was in response to a previous comment that has been deleted. The author of that comment observed that 1.305 is actually a slightly different number for the system, (due to the intrinsic binary representation, I believe). I pointed out that the same "problem" affects other numbers that are rounded "correctly" (e.g. 1.315). On the other hand, numbers that are represented exactly, like 0.125, are rounded in the "wrong" way. Hence, the problem does not seem to be in the binary representation.